# Button doesn't trigger an event

Tags: javascript, html

Please help me with the following code because I don't know what I am missing. A click on button Compute should trigger function `computeAll()`. Instead the script doesn't react to my actions:

the html code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="complex.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="calcul" method ="post">
        <table>
           <tr><th></th><th>Real part</th><th>Imaginary part(i)</th></tr>
          <tr><td>Enter the first complex number</td><td><input type="text" name="real1"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="imaginary1"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Enter the secound complex number</td><td><input type="text" name="real2"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="imaginary2"/></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Enter your choice</td><td colspan="2"><div><p>Addition<input type="radio" value="add" checked name="option">
        </p><p>Substraction<input type="radio" value="subs" name="option"></p></div>
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td >The answer is:</td><td><input type="text" name="displayReal"/></td><td><input type="text" name="displayImaginary"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td  colspan="3"></td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="Compute" onclick="computeAll()"></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearAll()"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

and java script code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function computeAll() {

        var val1, val2, img1, img2, resultR, resultI
        val1 = parseInt(document.calcul.real1.value);
        val2 = parseInt(document.calcul.real2.value);
        img1 = parseInt(document.calcul.imaginary1.value);
        img2 = parseInt(document.calcul.imaginary2.value);
        if (calcul.option[0].checked){
            resultR = val1 + val2;
        resultI = img1 + img2;
        document.calcul.displayReal.value = resultR;
        document.calcul.displayImaginary.value = resultI;

        }

        if (calcul.option[1].checked){
             resultR = val1 - val2;
        resultI = img1 - img2;
        document.calcul.displayReal.value = resultR;
        document.calcul.displayImaginary.value = resultI;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you debug are you sure it's not calling the method but running into an error within the method...

Comment: Test your code first in a browser dev tool, like Chrome or IE F12 window.

Comment: The javascript code you post is in `complex.js`?

Comment: This code works fine you need to check where the script tag is located

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is that `<script>` tag located? In the complex.js file referenced in `<head>`? You shouldn't need a `<script>` tag in a JavaScript file, which might be causing the issue. Check your browser's developer tools for any JS errors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the javascript code inside `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` when you referenced as external file (as in `<script src="complex.js"></script>`). Delete that, and try again.